# Calculate total costs of Loan

Tags: numerical-methods, percentages

**How are the total cost of a Loan calculated?**

I have this data and would like to know how I can calculate the total sum that I will have to pay to the bank:

---

13 Months, Loan Amount: 15132.08 Dollar

APRC:  12,0500 %

Interest Rate: 0,0795

12 Months: 528.83 Dollar

At the end bayback: 10233.17 Dollar

Service Fee: 35.00 Dollar Each Month

---

**Here's an payment plan for this loan:**

[image]

**I would like to know how to calculate the total to pay sum**

**I would simply sum up the Service Fee and The Kredit amount (35 * 14) + 15132.08 but how do I calculate the complete Interest to come to 16786.01?**

**How would you calculate it?** Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The interest for each period should be the existing balance times the interest rate times the time.  Your interest is just over $1\%$ per month, which should result in the kredit increasing by $1\%$ of the previous month's value.  You can see it is not doing this, so they are using some other way of calculating the interest.  The first month's interest should have been $15132.08 \cdot 0.1205/12 = 151.95$  The last month's interest (accepting their balance) should have been $10233.17 \cdot 0.1205/12 = 102.76$  Don't complain.